# validação de dados login/senha

Tags: java

criei 2 classes 
uma de conexão e outra dao

como eu conseguiria fazer uma validação de login/senha com essas duas classes

conexão

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package semeq;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author SpiriT
 */
public class ConnectionFactory {

private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/helpsemeq";
private static final String USER = "root";
private static final String PASS = "";

public static Connection getConnection(){

    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);     

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Erro na conexão: ",ex);
    }
}

public static void closeConnection(Connection con){

        try {
            if(con != null){
            con.close();
        } 

        }catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


public static void closeConnection(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt){

    closeConnection(con);

        try {
            if(stmt != null){
            stmt.close();
        } 

        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

public static void closeConnection(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt, ResultSet rs){

    closeConnection(con, stmt);

        try {
            if(rs != null){
            rs.close();
        } 

        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

dao

```
package semeq;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class daoSemeq {
private ResultSet rs;
private Statement stm;
private Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

public daoSemeq (){

}
public ResultSet getUserDAO () throws SQLException{
    this.stm = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    this.rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT login,senha FROM usuário");

    return this.rs;
}
}
```

minha dúvida e como eu cosneguiria fazer uma validação no form para checar o login e a senha digitada.

Answer (score 0):

Cara não entendi a que se refere sua classe DAO, mas vamos la... Pra inicio de conversa obviamente se quer fazer um loguin tens que ter no banco de dados as informações do loguin... Recomendo não salvar a senha de forma visivel lá, ja que qualquer um com acesso ao banco de dados vai poder ver todos os usuários e suas senhas... recomendo usar uma MD5 ou qualquer outra criptografia... Mas vamos la..
Para a classe UsuarioDAO a verificação poderia ser simples>>

```
public boolean verificarLoguin(Usuario u) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE loguin =" + u.getLoguin();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.first()) {
            if (rs.getString("senha").equals(u.getSenha())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        ConnnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, stmt, rs);
    }
}
```